# Python: Extract only some attributes from a csv file to a numpy array

Tags: python, csv, numpy, attributes, selection

I am trying to develop a Neural Network that reads its input from a csv file. I use this as a tutorial:
https://machinelearningmastery.com/multi-class-classification-tutorial-keras-deep-learning-library/

I understand how the input is stored in X

```
X = dataset[:,0:4].astype(float)
```

The problem is that the the dataset, I am going to use, has over 100 attributes per entry (unlike here that there are only 4). I have figured out which of them I want to use as an input but I can't find a way to create the X having the same format as in the example. I tried numpy.vstack but there was not the desired results.

Could anyone give me an example of how I could create the X including only specified attributes?

Comment: Have you tried the `usecols` parameter?

Comment: no. can you please help?

Comment: I used   X = numpy.loadtxt("IrisDataset.csv", delimiter=',', usecols=(0, 1, 2, 3))

Comment: the format is now ok but I still have a problem with the datatypes. Because the attributes I want to use are of different datatypes (unsigned, boolean, string, signed). I am not quite sure on how to use the dtype parameter.

Comment: You might find `genfromtxt` easier to use in this case.  It doesn't choke if it can't turn the items into the default `float`.  `dtype=None` tells it to deduce an appropriate dtype for each column.  I'd suggest trying that first, and look at the resulting array (esp. its dtype).  Then use that as a model for refining the field dtypes.

Comment: `np.genfromtxt` has examples of how to specify `dtype`.

Comment: thank you im gonna try this

Comment: I tried both numpy.loadtxt and numpy.genfromotxt but the format is not the same. Especially I used:
X = numpy.loadtxt("IrisDataset.csv", delimiter=",", usecols=(0,1,2,3,5),dtype ={'names': ('ticker', 'year', 'month','day','hi'),'formats': ('f2', 'f2', 'f2','f2', 'S2')})
I get the error:
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_1_input to have shape (5,) but got array with shape (1,)       after          
    results = cross_val_score(estimator, X, dummy_y, cv=kfold)

Comment: If your error is in the code following a successful load (no errors), I don't think we can help you in this question.  We don't know what `cross_val_score` accepts, and we don't know much about what you are giving it (other than `X` is a structured array).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common procedure is to use pandas which allows dtype soft conversion via [pandas.DataFrame.infer_objects](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.infer_objects.html) followed by [pandas.DataFrame.values](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html#pandas.DataFrame.values) that returns a Numpy representation of the DataFrame. Optionally, you can specify the columns to use with `usecols` as suggested above.

From the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

> **usecols** : list-like or callable, default `None`
>
> Return a subset of the
>   columns. If list-like, all elements must either be positional (i.e.
>   integer indices into the document columns) or strings that correspond
>   to column names provided either by the user in names or inferred from
>   the document header row(s).

**How does that look like?**

```
df = pd.read_csv(infile, usecols = ['a', 'b'])         # Read
df_dtypes = df.infer_objects()                         # Soft conversion
x = df.values                                          # Numpy array

print df.info()                                        # Inspect -> Object
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 3 entries, 0 to 2
Data columns (total 2 columns):
a    3 non-null object
b    3 non-null object
dtypes: object(2)
memory usage: 120.0+ bytes

print df_types.info()                                  # Inspect -> dtype change
  <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 3 entries, 0 to 2
Data columns (total 2 columns):
a    3 non-null int64
b    3 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(2)
memory usage: 120.0 bytes

print x                                                # Inspect -> numpy array
[[7 3]
 [1 2]
 [5 1]]
```

Comment: I didn't quite catch usecols = ['a', 'b']

Comment: I have included a reference to the docs of pandas.read_csv. please let me know if it works in your case

Comment: Thank you this actually worked. As a mentioned above what can I do if the attributes are of different datatype? Apart from floats, I have booleans, signed and unsigned ints and strings

Comment: Get rid of the usecols and try again. It should work for all the dtypes you mentioned, in case the respective dtype is the same for the whole column. Note that string will always be object. Also, if this worked, feel free to upvote my answer.

Comment: dtype ={'names': ('ticker', 'year', 'month','day','hi'),'formats': ('f2', 'f2', 'f2','f2', 'S2')

Comment: dataframe = pandas.read_csv("IrisDataset.csv", header=None, usecols = [0,1,2,3,5], dtype ={0:np.float32, 1:np.float32, 2:np.float32, 3:np.float32, 5: np.str })